# How to install ios app from pc(windows/linux)

Tags: ios, flutter

Through [Codemagic](https://codemagic.io/) I can build flutter app for ios. But how do I install it on ios without a mac?
[This](https://medium.com/flutter-community/developing-and-debugging-flutter-apps-for-ios-without-a-mac-8d362a8ec667) article talks about using [Cydia Impactor](http://www.cydiaimpactor.com/), which I've tried and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Simply, you can't.
iOS doesn't allow app installs from pc, you need a Mac with xCode and the iPhone attached to it.
There is no way to install via Widndows/Linux.
Cydia impactor will no install because the app needs to be compiled with a certificate that you need to buy from apple.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can with **AltSigner** is a free Cydia Impactor alternative tool that can be used to sign IPA on Windows to install app directly.